# nokia here map - re load the map issue

Tags: api, dictionary, here-api

I do need to refresh my map with different variables showing on the map according to the map selection. however, the map creates another instances and binds the map in another div. how should I re-load the map on the same spot on the html page ? thank you

such code:

```
cstext1.Append(" var mapContainer1 = document.getElementById(\"mapContainer\");");
cstext1.Append(" var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer1, {   center: [-37.75140353, 145.18385956],  zoomLevel: 15, components: [ new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(), new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(),         new nokia.maps.map.component.Traffic(), new nokia.maps.map.component.PublicTransport(),  new nokia.maps.map.component.DistanceMeasurement(), new nokia.maps.map.component.Overview(), new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar(),  new nokia.maps.positioning.component.Positioning(),  new nokia.maps.map.component.ContextMenu(),  new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomRectangle() ] });  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display( ... etc.
```

creates a new instance of the map each time. If you want to manipulate it you just need to reference the methods now available to the `map` variable  e.g.

```
map.set('zoomLevel', 10);
map.set('center', [51.23, 6.78]);
... etc
```

i.e. the methods of [nokia.maps.map.Display](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Display.html) rather than creating a new instance.